# How to create shuffled batch list from numpy arrays to feed tensorflow dictionnary

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

I am working on a classifier with Tensorflow. My input and output are numpy arrays with examples as rows and parameter as columns. My code is working correctly until now, and I could train my network by directly feeding 100% of my input and output arrays.
Now, I would like to create a list of shuffled batches to feed tensorflow, but this step is not so clear for me.

Does the following creates lists of tensors (my batches)?

```
input_batch,output_batch=tf.train.shuffle_batch([input,output],batch_size=100,capacity=50,min_after_dequeue=10,enqueue_many=True,allow_smaller_final_batch=True)
```

Then I am trying to feed this batches to tensorflow :

```
for epoch in range(0,2000):
     sess.run(train_step,feed_dict={X:input_batch.eval(),Yreal:output_batch.eval()})
```

But nothing happens after this line.

How can I correctly prepare batches from numpy arrays and feed it to tensorflow dictionnary?

Answer (score 1):

I finally found how to create different batches randomly for each epoch. I post my solution as it may be useful for someone else. So here is the trick.

```
for epoch in range(0,2000):
    permutation=np.random.permutation(input_size)
    permutation=permutation[0:batch_size]
    batch=[train_set[permutation],train_label[permutation]]
    sess.run(train_step,feed_dict={X:batch[0],Yreal:batch[1]})
```

It may not be the sexiest way, but it's working. We have a random list (permutation) created at each epoch from which we extract our batches. Each batch is then fed to tensorflow.